# Rails aways renders the application.html.erb instead of wanted views

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My Ruby on Rails application always renders the layouts/application.html.erb view instead the views I want it to. Has anyone an Idea why that might be so?
My routes file looks like this:

```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
     root 'startup#index'
     resources :users
   end
```

And my application_cotroller.rb is pretty much empty:

```
   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception
   end
```

Comment: mention the desired layout in the controller like this: `layout 'my_layout'`, and have the layout created in `app/views/layuts/my_layout.html.erb`.

Comment: can you put your `layouts/application.html.erb` code in your question? Did you put `<%= yield %>` in there where you want your views to be rendered?

Comment: no. Thank you very much. the yield part was missing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a controller action in Rails renders the view template for your action, wrapped up into a layout (which is `application/layout`)

ActionView::TemplateHandlers manages the lookup for the extension (.html.erb, .html.haml, .json.erb, etc ...)

so, in an action called index, you will get this implicit call unless you call `render` yourself :

```
def edit
  # your code
  render action :'edit', layout: 'application/layout' # implicitly called
end
```

Rails will then start processing your layout and put the content of your edit template in place of any `yield` within your layout. Thus, a typical layout will look like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- layout content before view -->

  <%= yield %>

  <!-- layout content after view -->
</body>
```